# How to calculate output from biquad filter equation?

Tags: matlab, filter, arduino

For a project I use a Due to sample a signal, apply a biquad filter and output the result to a DAC.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_biquad_filter I got the general formula;

(b0 + b1*z^-1 + b2*z^-2) / (a0 + a1*z^-1 + a2*z^-2)

I calculated the coefficients for a lowpass filter and got it working on a dedicated DSP.

However I do not understand how to apply this filter on an Arduino. Is there some way to 'multiply' the input with the filter to get the output, or how does that work?

Comment: When you sample the input you get a number.  When you write to the DAC it expects some number.  Can you multiply a number and a number to get a number?

Comment: In your link, you see that depending on the direct form you need a certain amount of registers to save the information of the past (of input samples and output samples). All you need to do is multiply your coefficients with the current values of the register and the incoming value and update the register afterwards.